# javascript code inside php echo

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my functional onClick script in HTML and it works perfectly:

```
<input type="text" id="t" name="t" value="1">
<a href="testar.php?action=" onclick="window.location=this.href+'&quant='+document.getElementById('t').value;return false;">Click</a>
```

What i want to achieve is this:

```
echo '<input type="text" value="1" id="t" name=""/>
<a href="addCarrinho.php?id_produto='.$registo['id'].'&nome='.$registo['nome'].'&preco='.$registo['preco'].'" onclick="window.location=this.href+'&quant='+document.getElementById('t').value;return false;">Add</a>';
```

All php works, i am receiving php variables on the other page but the onClick javaScript is not working, im getting a sintaxe error.
I think its a quotes problem but im not familiarized with javaScript.

Comment: The syntax highlighting in your question shows you the problem - escape the single quotes there using a backslash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to the following:

```
<a href="addCarrinho.php?id_produto='.$registo['id'].'&nome='.$registo['nome'].'&preco='.$registo['preco'].'" onclick="window.location=this.href+\'&quant=\'+document.getElementById(\'t\').value;return false;">Add</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the single quotes in the last line like following:

```
...
onclick="window.location=this.href+\'&quant=\'+document.getElementById(\'t\').value;return false;"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input type="text" value="1" id="t" name=""/>
<a href="addCarrinho.php?id_produto='.$registo["id"].'&nome='.$registo["nome"].'&preco='.$registo["preco"].'" onclick="window.location=this.href+'&quant='+document.getElementById("t").value;return false;">Add</a>';
```

Try with this way, I did some single and double quote change.